# Do Assassin Recruits die if the Templars retake a Den?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

When I liberate a Den from the Templars I normally fill up by new slots right away however I am wondering, if a den gets contended and I fail to repel the attack, do Assassin Recruits die if a den is retaken and what effect does this have on recruits out on missions.

Also if recruits do die, how does the game determine which ones are killed?

Comment: your recruits cannot be permenantly killed.

Comment: @Ramhound - perhaps you're thinking of AC III?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh yes, the recruits CAN be killed permanently!!! Try sending a recruit on a mission and fail it! He / she ain't coming back! ;-)

Since you have to place a certain assassin as the "den master" for him / her to even advance beyond a certain point, that very assassin is the one affected.

You do NOT lose your assassin if you lose a den defense, however. If you lose, you get ported right in front of the lost territory. Acquisition of that territory as per usual (killing the captain, lighting the signal fire). If you do, templar awareness jumps to the max though. The assassin is available again as soon as you recapture the den.

Just keep in mind, there is absolutely no reason to even let it come to that point. Ever. You always have the option to lower your notoriety. Even if you are notorious, you still have some time and notoriety level before one of your dens gets attacked. And lowering your notoriety is so easy (posters, town criers and special targets), that there is really no need for this to occur. :-)

Comment: I don't quite get your answer, i already know about assassins being killed from failing missions, what i was asking was assassins being killed if a Den is retaken, you can only assign an assassin as a Den Master once they reach Level 10 and there are points in the game where you can reduce you notoriety, such as when you kill the Leader of the Janissaries

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear, I do realize that this part was not answered directly. You do NOT lose your assassin if you lose a den defense. If you lose, you get ported right in front of the lost territory. Acquisition of that territory as per usual (killing the captain, lighting the signal fire). If you do, templar awareness jumps to the max though. The assassin is available again as soon as you recapture the den.

Comment: could you edit that into your answer

Comment: Done as asked. ;-)